# White spacing datagrid view

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview with a few rows.  I want to refrain user from clicking the white spaces (empty area after rows)

Or at least I could catch when user clicks the empty area, so a message could be displayed.

Please advise how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As
System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.MouseClick

    If ((DataGridView1.Rows(0).Height * DataGridView1.Rows.Count) + 
     DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeight) < e.Location.Y Then

        MsgBox("Empty Area")

    End If

End Sub
```